# Backbone events not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have created a simple view for backbone.js.

Can anybody see why this would not be triggering on click?

**Html/**

```
<form id=hello>
Email:
<input class=email>
Password:
<input class=password>
<span id="submit">submit</span>
</form>
```

**Js/**

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#hello',
    events: {
        'click #submit': 'clicked'
    },
    clicked: function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    }
});

var formView = new FormView();
```

Comment: Seems [fine](http://jsbin.com/aVabemo/1/) maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: It worked when I was trying your code.

Comment: Are you creating the view inside `$.ready`? Otherwise it might not be finding `#hello` when you create the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code worked for me. Did you wrap it in the jQuery ready function?

```
$(function() {
    var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
       el: '#hello',
       events: {
         'click #submit': 'clicked'
       },
       clicked: function(){
         console.log('clicked');
       }
    });

    var formView = new FormView();  
});
```

Or, do you have access to Backbone in the file?